# Newtonsoft JSON deserialize and write data

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following class Visual Studio created from the JSON pasted below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

-----JSON-----

[{"id":"00a17000000LmTOAA0","comments":"This is a comment or note added from code","createdDate":"2015-03-13T15:52:02.000+0000","modifiedDate":"2015-03-13T15:52:02.000+0000","createdBy":"Contact","modifiedBy":"Contact"},{"id":"00a17000000LmTTAA0","comments":"This is a comment or note added from code","createdDate":"2015-03-13T15:53:19.000+0000","modifiedDate":"2015-03-13T15:53:19.000+0000","createdBy":"Contact","modifiedBy":"Contact"},{"id":"00a17000000LmTYAA0","comments":"This is a comment or note added from code","createdDate":"2015-03-13T15:54:29.000+0000","modifiedDate":"2015-03-13T15:54:29.000+0000","createdBy":"Contact","modifiedBy":"Contact"},{"id":"00a17000000LmU7AAK","comments":"New Note Entered by Requester: This is a comment or note added from code","createdDate":"2015-03-13T16:39:43.000+0000","modifiedDate":"2015-03-13T16:39:43.000+0000","createdBy":"Contact","modifiedBy":"Contact"},{"id":"00a17000000LmW3AAK","comments":"added this comment from SalesF app as an agent","createdDate":"2015-03-13T17:37:24.000+0000","modifiedDate":"2015-03-13T17:37:24.000+0000","createdBy":"Agent","modifiedBy":"Agent"}]

I'm trying to create an object and do a foreach and get the data... I keep getting error Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly.

I have tried this among other things:

```
var jsonResponseNotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(GetCommentsByID());
```

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need the root class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string createdDate { get; set; }
    public string modifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Comment: @lopsided i'm sorry, mate. have a look at your upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of your object. You will need to deserialize as such. Your code should be:

```
var jsonResponseNotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(GetCommentsByID());
```

---

### Edit

Just noticed your root object property is an array. Still, I believe arrays deserialize into list objects. I've adjusted my code.